# Very slow filling of sparse matrix and no memory gain in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to implement an example that is given in the **Eigen** [tutorial](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html) as pseudocode. As far as I understand, it illustrates the recommended method for filling a sparse matrix, provided that the number of non zero entries per column is known.

The pseudocode is found under the Header "**Filling a sparse Matrix**"and is written as follows:

```
1: SparseMatrix<double> mat(rows,cols);         // default is column major
2: mat.reserve(VectorXi::Constant(cols,6));
3: for each i,j such that v_ij != 0
4:   mat.insert(i,j) = v_ij;                    // alternative: mat.coeffRef(i,j) += v_ij;
5: mat.makeCompressed();                        // optional
```

My attempt to transform it into C is found below. I have (hopefully) written vee() such, that it will create 2500 non-zero elements per column. Therefore 2500 should correspond to 6 in the example. I set it to 3000 to test make.Compressed as well.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the behaviour of the programme. It does i=0...3000 in seconds, then is stuck for minutes. Then it goes to 6000 and is stuck again for minutes. Why is that and how to get better performance?

Furthermore, the memory usage is very strange. You can see that at times toward the end Eigen uses significantly more memory than needed for the corresponding dense matrix in GSL.The memory used also fluctuates wildly. in steps bigger than 100MB

I compile and run like this:

> ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$ g++ -o eigenfill.x eigenfill.cc -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas && ./eigenfill.x

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#define rows 1e4
#define cols 1e4



/*-- DECLARATIONES --*/
int FillMatrix(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> mat);
double vee(int i, int j);

int main()
{
printf("---> Watch gsl matrix memory usage!\n");    
gsl_matrix *testmat = gsl_matrix_calloc(rows, cols);
sleep(20);
gsl_matrix_free(testmat);
printf("---> Watch eigen matrix memory usage!\n");  

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> mat(rows,cols);         // default is column major
FillMatrix(mat);
printf("------------------------DONE");
return(0);
}

/*-- --*/
int FillMatrix(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> mat)
{
int i, j;
Eigen::VectorXd Vres;
mat.reserve(Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(cols,3000));
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        if(i%500==0){printf("i= %i\n", i);}
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
        if (vee(i,j) != 0){mat.insert(i,j) = vee(i,j);    /*alternative: mat.coeffRef(i,j) += v_ij;*/ }
        }

    }
printf("--->starting compression"); 
mat.makeCompressed();

return(0);
}
/*-- --*/
double vee(int i, int j)
{
    double result = 0.0;

    if(j%4 == 0){result =1.0;}

    return result;
}
/*-- --*/
```

**EDIT**

One answer reminded me I needed to use addresses, because the local variables of FillMatrix() will be gone when it runs through. I tried the following, which does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#define rows 1e4
#define cols 1e4



/*-- DECLARATIONES --*/
int FillMatrix(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> & mat);
double vee(int i, int j);

int main()
{
printf("---> Watch gsl matrix memory usage!\n");    
gsl_matrix *testmat = gsl_matrix_calloc(rows, cols);
sleep(20);
gsl_matrix_free(testmat);
printf("---> Watch eigen matrix memory usage!\n");  

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> mat(rows,cols);         // default is column major
FillMatrix(& mat);
printf("------------------------>DONE\n");
return(0);
}

/*-- --*/
int FillMatrix(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> &mat)
{
int i, j;
Eigen::VectorXd Vres;
mat.reserve(Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(cols,3000));
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        if(i%500==0){printf("i= %i\n", i);}
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
        if (vee(i,j) != 0){mat.insert(i,j) = vee(i,j);    /*alternative: mat.coeffRef(i,j) += v_ij;*/ }
        }

    }
printf("--->starting compression\n");   
mat.makeCompressed();

return(0);
}
/*-- --*/
double vee(int i, int j)
{
    double result = 0.0;

    if(i%4 == 0){result =1.0;}

    return result;
}
/*-- --*/
```

The error messages are:

```
ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$ g++ -o eigenfill.x eigenfill.cc -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas && ./eigenfill.x
eigenfill.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
eigenfill.cc:24:17: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>*’
 FillMatrix(& mat);
                 ^
eigenfill.cc:12:5: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘int FillMatrix(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>&)’
 int FillMatrix(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> & mat);
     ^
ludi@ludi-M17xR
```

**EDIT** 
And it compiles if I write:

> FillMatrix(mat);

instead of

> FillMatrix(&mat);

I don't understand. Should not the last one be correct?

Comment: You should not ask two questions in the same entry. Anyway, you indeed still need to call `FillMatrix` as: `FillMatrix(mat);` because FillMatrix expect a reference, not a pointer!

Comment: @ggael Thank you. I am sorry. I still don't understand completely about &mat, but I will create a new question with a small programme comparing &mat and &double, so that I don't steal away people's chance for gaining reputation. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are entirely filling one column over four. It looks like the following:

```
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
...
```

Replacing `j%4 == 0` by `i%4 == 0` will do the job. The memory usage will be exactly: `2500*cols*(sizeof(double)+sizeof(int)) + cols*sizeof(int)`.

You must also fix the prototype of `FillMatrix` so that you fill the real matrix and not a temporary:

```
int FillMatrix(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> &mat);
```

Finally, if your goal is really to work with sparse matrices having about 1/4 of non zeros, then a dense representation will likely be faster.

Comment: Thank you very much. The matrices I will be targeting in reality have 1/4 of non zeroes, but distributed in a more complicated fashion. What I am hoping to accelerate is the product sparse matrix * dense vector. Are you saying, that the matrix is not sparse enough, so the product will not benefit?

Comment: Can there be a fundamental difference between rows andd columns? Could I change from row major to column major to make the original matrix take up lesser memory too?

Comment: When I rewrite everything to &mat, it does not compile.

Comment: yes, with 1/4 of non-zeros uniformly spread, a dense matrix will be much faster. However, if some rows/columns are entirely zero, then remove them from the rhs/result, and still use a dense matrix.