# Should Eigen dense matrix * dense vector multiplication be 7 times slower than GSL?

Tags: c++, eigen

The answer to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286299/very-slow-filling-of-sparse-matrix-and-no-memory-gain-in-eigen) made me expect that (for matrices with 1/4 of non-vanishing entries) in Eigen the product
Dense Matrix * Dense Vector 
should outperform 
Sparse Matrix*Dense Vector.

Not only do I see the opposite, but also both are outperformed by GSL by a factor of 7 and 4 respectively.

Am I using Eigen incorrectly? Am I timing carelessly? I am very startled.

My compile options read:

> ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$ g++ -o eigenfill.x eigenfill.cc -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas && ./eigenfill.x

My code reads:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#define helix 100
#define rows helix*helix
#define cols rows
#define filling rows/4
#define REPS 10


using namespace Eigen;

/*-- DECLARATIONES --*/
int FillSparseMatrix(SparseMatrix<double> & mat);
int FillDenseMatrices(MatrixXd & Mat, gsl_matrix *testmat);
double vee(int i, int j);
int set_vectors_randomly(gsl_vector * v2, VectorXd v1);

int main()
{
int rep;
    struct timeval tval_before, tval_after, tval_result;

gsl_matrix *testmat     = gsl_matrix_calloc(rows, cols);
gsl_vector *v2      =gsl_vector_calloc(cols);
gsl_vector *prod    =gsl_vector_calloc(cols);

SparseMatrix<double> mat(rows,cols);         // default is column major
MatrixXd Mat(rows,cols);         // default is column major
VectorXd v1(cols), vv1(cols);

FillSparseMatrix(mat);
FillDenseMatrices(Mat, testmat);
    printf("\n/*--- --- --- ---*/\n");
for(rep=0;rep<REPS;rep++)
{
set_vectors_randomly(v2, v1);

    gettimeofday(&tval_before, NULL);       
vv1 = mat*v1;
    gettimeofday(&tval_after, NULL);
    timersub(&tval_after, &tval_before, &tval_result);

    printf("Time for one product, SPARSE EIGEN / secs: %ld.%06ld\n", (long int)tval_result.tv_sec, (long int)tval_result.tv_usec);
    gettimeofday(&tval_before, NULL);       
gsl_blas_dgemv( CblasNoTrans,1.0, testmat, v2, 0.0, prod);
    gettimeofday(&tval_after, NULL);
    timersub(&tval_after, &tval_before, &tval_result);
    printf("Time for one product, GSL / secs: %ld.%06ld\n", (long int)tval_result.tv_sec, (long int)tval_result.tv_usec);

    gettimeofday(&tval_before, NULL);       
vv1 = Mat*v1;
    gettimeofday(&tval_after, NULL);
    timersub(&tval_after, &tval_before, &tval_result);
    printf("Time for one product, DENSE EIGEN / secs: %ld.%06ld\n", (long int)tval_result.tv_sec, (long int)tval_result.tv_usec);
    printf("/*--- --- --- ---*/\n\n");


  //std::cout << mat << std::endl;
}
gsl_matrix_free(testmat);   
printf("--- --- --->DONE\n");
return(0);
}

/*-- --*/
int FillSparseMatrix(SparseMatrix<double> &mat)
{
int i, j;
Eigen::VectorXd Vres;
mat.reserve(Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(cols,filling));

printf("Filling Sparse Matrix ...");
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        if(i%2500==0){printf("i= %i\n", i);}
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
        if (vee(i,j) != 0){mat.insert(i,j) = vee(i,j);    /*alternative: mat.coeffRef(i,j) += v_ij;*/ }
        }

    }

return(0);
}
/*-- --*/

/*-- --*/
int FillDenseMatrices(MatrixXd &Mat, gsl_matrix * testmat)
{
int i, j;
Eigen::VectorXd Vres;
double aux;
printf("Filling Dense Matrix ...");
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        if(i%2500==0){printf("i= %i\n", i);}
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
        aux = vee(i,j);
        if (aux != 0)
        {
        Mat(i,j) = aux;    
        gsl_matrix_set(testmat, i, j, aux);
        }
        }

    }
return(0);
}
/*-- --*/

double vee(int i, int j)
{
    double result = 0.0;

    if(i%4 == 0){result =1.0;}

    return result;
}
/*-- --*/
int set_vectors_randomly(gsl_vector * v2, VectorXd v1){
printf("Setting vectors rendomly anew ...\n");
for (int j=0;j<cols;j++) 
{
double r=drand48();
v1(j) =r;
gsl_vector_set(v2, j, r);

}
return(0);
}
/*-- --*/
```

Comment: You should add an optimization flag -O2 or -O3 when compiling.

Comment: Indeed. Now both outperform GSL and the sparse one is best. Would you like to write an answer and get some points? ;)

Comment: You can speed it up a little bit more by adding the -DNDEBUG flag. This will disable bounds checking.

Comment: Can the culprit explain why he down voted this question? This seems important and non-trivial to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Eigen, performance is abysmal when compiling without compiler optimizations. There are several ways to increase performance dramatically:

- With optimizations turned on (-O2 or -O3 in g++) performance can be two-three orders of magnitude higher.
- An additional (smaller) speedup can be attained by defining `NDEBUG` before including the Eigen library. This disables bounds checking, so make sure there are no issues before enabling this feature.
- [Eigen can also take advantage of vectorization](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_can_I_enable_vectorization.3F) (SSE as of 3.2.6 and AVX as of 3.3, PowerPC and ARM as well) leading to further speedups. Just enable the relevant flags in your compiler.
- [Enabling OMP](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) can lead to speedups as well. Again, enable the relevant flags in your compiler and Eigen will do the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you give a hint how the last two points can be done?

Comment: Instead of enabling vectorization for the specific architecture manually, you should add the compiler flag `-march=native`

Comment: @DimitriLesnoff unless you’re compiling for a machine or machines other than the one you’re compiling on.

Comment: OP didn't mention anything concerning cross-compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Spaesematrix is columnmajor by default which is not suitable for product with vector. Use Spaesematrix and you would find it be more fast.