# Is Eigen library matrix/vector manipulation faster than .net ones if the matrix is dense and unsymmetrical?

Tags: c++, .net, matrix, eigen

I have some matrix operations, mostly dealing with operations like running over all the each of the rows and columns of the matrix and perform multiplication `a*mat[i,j]*mat[ii,j]`:

```
public double[] MaxSumFunction()
{
   var maxSum= new double[vector.GetLength(1)];
   for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
   {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++) 
        {
             for (int ii = 0; ii < matrix.GetLength(0); ii++)
              {
                   double wi= Math.Sqrt(vector[i]);
                   double wii= Math.Sqrt(vector[ii]);
                   maxSum[j] += SomePowerFunctions(wi, wii) * matrix[i, j]*matrix[ii, j];
              }
          }                      
     }
 }

    private double SomePowerFunctions(double wi, double wj)
    {

        var betaij = wi/ wj;
        var numerator = 8 * Math.Sqrt(wi* wj) * Math.Pow(betaij, 3.0 / 2)
            * (wi+ betaij * wj);
        var dominator = Math.Pow(1 - betaij * betaij, 2) +
            4 * wi* wj* betaij * (1 + Math.Pow(betaij, 2)) +
            4 * (wi* wi+ wj* wj) * Math.Pow(betaij, 2);


        if (wi== 0 && wj== 0)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(betaij - 1) < 1.0e-8)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        return numerator / dominator;
    }
```

I found such loops to be particularly slow if the matrix size is big.

I want the speed to be fast. So I am thinking about re-implementing these algorithms using the Eigen library.

My matrix is not symmetrical, not sparse and contains no regularity that any solver can exploit reliably.

I read that [Eigen solver can be fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33386341/3834) because of:

1. Compiler optimization
2. Vectorization
3. [Multi-thread support](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html)

But I wonder those advantages are really applicable given my matrix characteristics?

Note: I could have just run a sample or two to find out, but I believe that asking the question here and have it documented on the Internet is going to help others as well.

Comment: I don't understand... if performance is all you need, why don't you use something low-level such as OpenBLAS? Why do you need to reinvent the wheel for matrix multiplication that people spent decades optimizing? The operation you marked up there: `mat[i,j]*mat[ii,j]`, is simply matrix multiplication with the transpose `mat[j,ii]`. Any BLAS interfaced library can do that for you. Also btw, just looping like that is the slowest way you can do this. You can still get much better performance if you can do this with `std::transform`, which will enable vectorization for you.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, 1) `mat[i,j]*mat[ii,j]` this is not a transpose operation 2), I am using C# so `std::transform` doesn't help 3) I see no reason in prefering OpenBlas over Eigen, I know Eigen well, but OpenBlas, not so.

Comment: I never said it's a transpose operation, I said, it's a multiplication with the transpose of `mat[ii,j]`, so it's mat[i,j]*Tr(mat[j,ii]), which means that this operation can be reduced to matrix multiplication, and since matrix multiplication is the oldest problem in the book, you should consider using BLAS, because it's THE library for linear algebra. Doesn't matter if it's OpenBLAS specifically (which is an implementation of BLAS), but, again, you'd be reinventing the wheel there. I had quantum mechanics problems with matrix multiplications of sizes over 10000x10000, so take a look at BLAS.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, great explanation. Let me check it out

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, I don't think this can directly be cast as a matrix-matrix product because the summation does not operate on the common index `j`. On the other hand, if you see `f(wi,wii)` as a matrix, then you can do something... Also, Eigen delivers similar performance magnitude than other optimized BLAS implementation, it also exposes a BLAS compatible API, and can use another BLAS implementation....

Comment: I've edited my previous answer to describe how to rewrite it as a matrix product using Eigen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before thinking about low level optimizations, look at your code and observe that many quantities are recomputed many time. For instance, `f(wi,wii)` does not depend on `j`, so they could either be precomputed once (see below) or you can rewrite your loop to make the loop on j the nested one. Then the nested loop will simply be a coefficient wise product between a constant scalar and two columns of your matrix (I don't .net and assume j is indexing columns). If the storage if column-major, then this operation should be fully vectorized by your compiler (again, I don't know .net, but any C++ compiler will do, and if you Eigen, it will be vectorized explicitly). This should be enough to get a huge performance boost.

Depending on the sizes of `matrix`, you might also try to leverage optimized matrix-matrix implementation by precomputed `f(wi,wii)` into a `MatrixXd F;` (using Eigen's language), and then observe that the whole computation amount to:

```
VectorXd v = your_vector;
MatrixXd F = MatrixXd::nullaryExpr(n,n,[&](Index i,Index j) {
                 return SomePowerFunctions(sqrt(v(i)), sqrt(v(j)));
             });
MatrixXd M = your_matrix;
MatrixXd FM = F * M;
VectorXd maxSum = (M.array() * FM.array()).colwise().sum();
```